# A good pattern for access control

Tags: zend-framework2, aop, acl, rbac

I have been working on a Zend Framework 2 application.  It has a service layer that wraps the model layer.  The controllers call the service layer, which talks to the model and the mapper.

The problem I am finding is that access control is taking a lot of effort, including testing effort.  The application uses a social graph, so access rules are quite complex.  For example, if User A wants to access a particular category of info about User B, they might need to be a certain type of user, and might need a certain number of connections to B.

Some of the access rules seem to belong within the model layer.  To put them in the service layer I would have to leak model functionality into the service.  Others seem to belong in the service layer, for example, those that pull a collection of objects from the mapper (the mapper has no concept of access control).

Has anyone had experience with these kinds of access control complexities?  It's not that the system doesn't work, it's just that 50% of code (and testing, mocking, etc) is taken up with access control.  Is there an easier way?

I have considered making access control event driven - each secure method would trigger an event, and the listeners of that event would throw an exception if required.  (I would not attach the listeners when testing, so I save about half of the test cases).  Has anyone had experience with this?

I tried ACL and RBAC quite a while back but could not find a satisfactory solution.  I looked into XACML about a year back, but it seemed like overkill, and even then I'm not sure it would solve the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I am an expert in Aspect-Oriented Programming in PHP, I think that you should have a look at this paradigm, because it was designed by Xerox PARC for solving cross-cutting concerns in a object-oriented code.

Your question about access control describes typical scattered functionality and you are right that this code is duplicated everywhere, because traditional object-oriented paradigm has not an answer how to do this elegantly.

Possible solution with OOP is to create decorators that can check for access rights. Alternative way is to modify each API method of a class to [trigger an event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/class_extension.html) and prepare a security handler that will check access rights during event dispatching. Both solutions are not perfect.

In the JAVA world AOP has been used for access control for a long time (eg. with AspectJ, [Spring](http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-aop-security)). I have developed Go! AOP framework for PHP that is ported version of Spring framework, powered by AOP Alliance interfaces.

Let's have a look how can we do this with AOP. Main class contains several business methods with domain logic:

```php
class MyService {
    public function updateProfile() {...}
    public function deleteProfile() {...}
}
```

Then we mark our method with doctrine annotation `@Secured(PROFILE_EDIT)` and define an aspect that will intercept execution of methods with this annotation everywhere in the source code:

```php
use Go\Aop\Aspect;
use Go\Aop\Intercept\MethodInvocation;
use Go\Lang\Annotation\Before;

/**
 * Security aspect
 */
class SecurityAspect implements Aspect
{
    /**
     * This advice intercepts an execution of secured methods
     *
     * Logic is pretty simple: we check an access rights before original method and
     * then invoke original method or throw an exception.
     *
     * @param MethodInvocation $invocation Invocation
     *
     * @Before("@annotation(Demo\Annotation\Secured)")
     */
    public function beforeSecuredMethod(MethodInvocation $invocation)
    {
        $right = $invocation->getMethod()->getAnnotation('Demo\Annotation\Secured')->value;
        if (!Security::isGranted($right)) {
            throw new AuthorizationException("Access denied. {$right} is required.");
        }
    }
}
```

You can read a more detailed article about [logging with AOP](http://go.aopphp.com/blog/2013/07/21/implementing-logging-aspect-with-doctrine-annotations/) to have an idea how this can be implemented for authorization. I also have a [working demo of logging aspect for Zend Framework2](http://zf2.aopphp.com/?aspect) to check the performance and [more examples](http://demo.aopphp.com/?showcase=cacheable).